# How to solve Jupyter Lab 500 internal server error?

Tags: jupyter-lab

I accidentally created an unnecessary repository on Jupyter Lab and when I try to delete or rename it, I get an error as can be seen in the picture below:

[image: 500 internal server error]

Anyone have an idea about how to fix it? I am a bit obsessed about the documentation order in my repository files, so there should be no unnecessary file remains in my active directory.

When I tried to delete the file, I was sure there was no kernel running. Secondly, I switched to another environment then tried to delete it but received the same error again. (Also deleting it from the file path was impossible too.)

I will really appreciate if anyone could propose a solution for this annoying bug.

Comment: HTTP 5XX server errors usually mean that the error is on their end.  (4XX error codes are reserved for user errors on your end.)  So I imagine something is wrong with the Jupyter servers.  Do you get this error for any of your other repositories?

Comment: No I received this error only for that repository, I can make deletion or edit other files under the same file path.

Answer (score 0):

Well... after all the things I've done for solving this bug, it was sad to realize that shutting down all the jupyter files running in the background from task manager would be enough.

-problem solved-